# Reading data from snowflake using pyspark throws SnowflakeLoggedFeatureNotSupportedException

Tags: pyspark, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Good day,

I am using a sample code from snowflake documentation on using pyspark to connect to it:

```
sfparams = {
        "sfURL": "SOME_URL",
        "sfUser": "SOME_USER",
        "sfPassword": "SOME_PASSWORD",
        "sfDatabase": "SOME_DB",
        "sfSchema": "SOME_SCHEMA",
        "sfWarehouse": "SOME_WH",
        "sfRole": "sysadmin"
    }

df = self.spark_sql_context\
             .read\
             .format('snowflake')\
             .options(**sfparams)\
             .option('query', "SELECT * FROM TABLE1 LIMIT 10")\
             .load()
df.show(truncate = False)
```

I have downloaded the required jar files (`snowflake-jdbc-3.9.2.jar` and `spark-snowflake_2.11-2.9.3-spark_2.4.jar`) and put them inside spark jars directory. Have also added the following to spark config:

```
.set("spark.jars", "/path_to/spark-2.4.5-bin-without-hadoop/jars/snowflake-jdbc-3.4.2.jar") \
.set("spark.jars", "/path_to/spark-2.4.5-bin-without-hadoop/jars/spark-snowflake_2.11-2.9.3-spark_2.4.jar")
```

However, whenever I try to run the code above, the following exception shows up:

```
: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/snowflake/client/jdbc/SnowflakeLoggedFeatureNotSupportedException
    at net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:318)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:223)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:211)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:167)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeLoggedFeatureNotSupportedException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 16 more
```

Couldn't find anything anywhere on how to deal with it so here I am.

Answer (score 0):

Educated guess. As the query is simple `.option('query', "SELECT * FROM TABLE1 LIMIT 10")\`

it may contain a column with not supported data type like BLOB/BINARY. If that is the case then explicit column list and omitting such column will help.

[Using the Spark Connector - From Snowflake to Spark SQL](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/spark-connector-use.html#from-snowflake-to-spark-sql)